# Can iptables forgets the packet state and do I have to add extra stateless rules after my stateful rules in this case?

Tags: iptables, firewall

As I understand, iptables can potentially forget the packet state? Is this right? If yes, do I have to add extra stateless rules?

For example, I have these rules.

```
iptables -A INPUT -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -o eth0 -p udp --dport 53 -m state --state NEW -j ACCEPT
```

Do I have to add following rules?

```
iptables -A OUTPUT -o eth0 -p udp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -p udp --sport 53 -j ACCEPT
```

Or do I get everything completely wrong?

Thanks is advance.

Comment: When do you think iptables would forget the packet state? I haven't seen anything like that. Please elaborate the exact cirumstances where you think Linux connection tracking would forget state? Otherwise, the rules are OK if you only send DNS queries to DNS servers.

Comment: @TeroKilkanen I'm speaking about cases, when the connection table can become full. Like in [this post](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/43205/nf-conntrack-table-full-dropping-packet).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, those rules make sure that DNS queries and responses are always passed through the firewall.

However, those rules make the firewall a bit more open, since any UDP packets sent from outside port 53 can reach any UDP port behing the firewall.